# añadir una url externa al webpack

Tags: url, webpack

alguien sabe como añadir una url externa al webpack.
Tengo unas librerías en una url que quiero que cuando pase a producción con webpack se me añadan las librerías. Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

La idea es enlazar librerías externas en desarrollo y cuando se pase a producción con webpack se incluyan y no se llamen de forma externa.

Muchas gracias

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
main: 'https://url.com/libreria.js'
 },
output: {
       path: './build/',
        filename: '[name].js',
    }
 };
```

Comment: Hola Alfredo y bienvenido SOes, La pregunta que acabas de hacer tiene poco contenido y explicación. Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento de la comunidad y de paso ganar tu primera medalla! También por [como elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así mejorar la tuya y ayudarte a que los usuario contesten mas rápidamente y con mas precisión a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las funciones external de webpack, es lo único que hay a ese respecto. Pero te costaría menos añadir las dependencias vía npm y cargarlas en scripts locales. Te pongo ejemplo con jquery.

## instalar jquery

```
npm i -D jquery
```

## main.js

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

## WEBPACK

```
module.exports = {
entry: {
main: 'main.js'
 },
output: {
       path: './build/',
        filename: '[name].js',
    }
 };
```

## INFO EXTERNALS

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  }
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: mi idea es que se utilice en desarrollo el enlace externo de url a la líbrería y cuando pongas en producción, te descargue a local todo y no hacer enlaces a urls externas. Esto como lo podría hacer, alguna idea?